# What is the most efficient way to fade out passed frames on canvas while animating on it?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm making something similar to a visualizer using HTML Canvas.  Upon drawing each frame, I would like to take the current canvas data and fade it out.

A few ways I've found of getting this effect are:

1. Drawing a semi-translucent box of the backdrop color over the entire canvas.  Doesn't actually fade out the content, so anything behind the canvas gets covered.  This is fast enough, and the fact that it can be done proves browsers are capable of all the necessary calculations.
2. Using canvas.getImageData(), manipulating the image data, and then using canvas.putImageData() to reapply it.  Doing this is super inefficient, putting tons of what should be native logic into js.  Too slow for any real use.
3. Using canvas.toDataUrl() to generate an image (png/jpg) and using ctx.globalOpacity to redraw that image with some transparency.  The steps taken in converting the canvas data to an image and back are very expensive (compression, headers, etc.).  Too slow for any real use.

**How can I fade out my passed frames on a canvas while animating new frames over the top?**

I have checked these:

[Canvas Fade Out Particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675035/canvas-fade-out-particles) - very similar problem, answer suggests a non-applicable solution to my problem (using sprites and redrawing the entire canvas)

[FadeIn FadeOut in Html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258169/fadein-fadeout-in-html5-canvas) - question is in regards to fading in/out an image on a canvas, not the canvas content itself.

EDIT: I think I may have found a solution:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing

Comment: The second example is using `ctx.globalAlpha`. Is what I would use in order to fade out the whole canvas. The first example is fading out **particle by particle** using rgba & hsla colors. You suggest using canvas.getImageData() & canvas.putImageData(). This is extremely expensive in terms of efficiency. Also you may use css opacity

Comment: @enxaneta I would like to use ctx.globalAlpha to fade out the entire canvas, but the only way to get the image data (I can find) is by converting to a png first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compositing did the trick.  Here's the fade out stage:

```
// painter = canvas.getContext("2d")
painter.save();
painter.globalAlpha = 1;
painter.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
const fadeOutAmount = 0.99;
painter.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, fadeOutAmount)";
painter.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
painter.restore();
```

By using a "destination-in" composite mode for drawing shapes, the new shapes opacity gets applied to the background.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing

Example ([also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/SephReed/pen/ePOoML)):

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 0, 0)";
// rectangle is filled with solid red
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5)";
ctx.fillRect(75, 75, 100, 100);
// after the line above, only the part where the two squares show is overlappped, and it only has the opacity of the latter square.  Doing this many frames in a row fully fades out the background.
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"

document.getElementById("test").appendChild(canvas);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: When I run that (either on CodePen or in the Stack Snippet the answer that I copied the CodePen into), all I see is a rectangle, no fade operation...? (I also tried putting the canvas in the DOM before the other operations, but that didn't change anything.)

Comment: Try commenting out the line `ctx.fillRect(75, 75, 100, 100);`. You'll see a much larger unfaded red square.  I'll add some comments

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused, though. Didn't you say you wanted a fade to occur? One doesn't in the above. (I'm just really keen to see this stuff happen, is all. :-) )

Comment: It's one frame worth of fading.  It's really just a proof that it works.  If it were to totally fade out, it would disappear quickly after loading the page and never show again, which seemed more confusing.